# How to get method name from inside that method without using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, methods, system.reflection

I want get the method name from inside itself.  This can be done using `reflection` as shown below. But, I want to get that without using `reflection`

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```

Sample code

```
public void myMethod()
{
    string methodName =  // I want to get "myMethod" to here without using reflection. 
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From C# 5 onwards you can get the compiler to fill it in for you, like this:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public static class Helpers
{
    public static string GetCallerName([CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {
        return caller;
    }
}
```

In `MyMethod`:

```
public static void MyMethod()
{
    ...
    string name = Helpers.GetCallerName(); // Now name=="MyMethod"
    ...
}
```

Note that you can use this *wrongly* by passing in a value explicitly:

```
string notMyName = Helpers.GetCallerName("foo"); // Now notMyName=="foo"
```

In C# 6, there's also `nameof`:

```
public static void MyMethod()
{
    ...
    string name = nameof(MyMethod);
    ...
}
```

That doesn't guarantee that you're using the same name as the method name, though - if you use `nameof(SomeOtherMethod)` it will have a value of `"SomeOtherMethod"` of course. But if you get it right, then refactor the name of `MyMethod` to something else, any half-decent refactoring tool will change your use of `nameof` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reference from C# 6.0

Answer (score 5):

As you said that you don't want to do using reflection then You can use `System.Diagnostics` to get method name like below:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public void myMethod()
{
     StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
     // get calling method name
     string methodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;
}
```

> Note : Reflection is far faster than stack trace method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @BandaraKamal Jon Skeet's answer is better than me. Also he has given references from latest C# versions. So consider accepting his answer.